# Bootstrap V5 Form Validation & Sweetalert2 : Showing success message after successful submission

Tags: javascript, html, validation, bootstrap-5

I have simple form based on Bootstrap 5 with a validation option I'm trying to display alert message if the form field is successfuly submited using Sweatalert2.

**Here is my Code :**

**HTML**

```
    <form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <label for="validationCustomUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group has-validation mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername" placeholder="Username *" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please choose a username.
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

[**Live Example**](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/ZELeNOM)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789010/how-to-use-html-form-checkvalidity/45789752) which quite helpful.

Below code might help:

```
......
 form.classList.add('was-validated');


                    if (form.reportValidity()) {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        Swal.fire({
                            position: 'center',
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Your application has been submitted successfully!',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 2500
                        }).then((result) => {
                            // Reload the Page
                            location.reload();
                        });
                    }
```

It will reload the page after form submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be too late, but I hope it can help others. I have the same issue. Then, I tried to combine bootstrap validation inside the SweetAlert Confirmation Box before submitting the form.
I create the code like below:

```js
$('#submitForm').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();// prevent form submit
    /*this part is taken from bootstrap validation*/
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }
        else {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "It cannot be undone",
                type: 'warning',
                icon: 'question',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send it!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    /*submit the form*/
                    $("#formsubmitsekali").submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }, false);
});
```

**`submitForm`** is the ID name for the button ID for submit the form.
**`formsubmitsekali`** is the form ID.

By doing so, if the required field is not filled, it will show the bootstrap validation without showing Sweetalert confirmation box. But if all of required fields are filled, the Sweetalert will show up.
The same behavior also happens if you have email input type, but it is filled by non-email, it will run the bootstrap validation first. It is also work if you use HTML5 pattern inside the input type and the user fills with the wrong pattern.