# Bootstrap 5 validating on submit but not showing invalid field hints

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I boiled down an example of a Laravel app that uses Bootstrap 5.0 and Javascript.  The validation works at the Javascript level but incorrectly filled in or empty fields are never highlighted by Bootstrap for entry on failure.  Your specific route for stackexchange.blade.php must be coded Route::any('Route','stackexchange')'.   My question is why this is happening? Can you suggest a fix.

```js
//pagescript2.js
function sendJSON(ip_address)
{
     let o = {
         ip:ip_address
     }
     alert(JSON.stringify(o));
     //call Zapier webhook with Fetch API.

   return true;
}

function VForm(ip_address)
{
        //Check forms validity, call redirecting method.
        if ($('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
        sendJSON(ip_address);

        //This redirects as expected
        window.location.href="https://www.yahoo.com";

    }

        return false;
}
```

```html
<!-- stackexchange.blade.php-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/landingpages/pagescript2.js')}}"></script>

<form method = "POST" onsubmit="return VForm('<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>');" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input id= "fname" class="form-control" name="fname" type = "text" required />

        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id = "email" class="form-control"  name="email" type="email" required/>


    </div>
    <button value="Submit" type="submit">Send Up!!</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this answers your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789010/how-to-use-html-form-checkvalidity/45789752

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.    How would I get bootstrap to highlight the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to delete this code `novalidate`, so that the validation works well

```js
//pagescript2.js
function sendJSON(ip_address)
{
     let o = {
         ip:ip_address
     }
     alert(JSON.stringify(o));
     //call Zapier webhook with Fetch API.

   return true;
}

function VForm(ip_address)
{
        //Check forms validity, call redirecting method.
        if ($('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
        sendJSON(ip_address);

        //This redirects as expected
        window.location.href="https://www.yahoo.com";

    }

        return false;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/landingpages/pagescript2.js')}}"></script>

<form method = "POST" onsubmit="return VForm('<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>');" class="needs-validation">
    
    <div>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input id= "fname" class="form-control" name="fname" type = "text" required />

        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id = "email" class="form-control"  name="email" type="email" required/>


    </div>
    <button value="Submit" type="submit">Send Up!!</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks sikurro.  Works like a champ now.